# How can we show Nifty window modal popup on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nifty-modal

I want to show my [nifty window modal popup](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/) on page load. This is my nifty window popup modal code:

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is my first nifty modal window. </p>

            <button class="md-close">Close me!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `md-show` class in document ready

Answer (score 0):

I've looking in to the source code of the demos, and I believe that this would do the trick:

```
$(function() {
     $('#modal-1').addClass('md-show');
});
```